# importing bacpac file using sql package

Tags: azure-sql-database, import, bacpac, sqlpackage

How can I specify Database maximum size when importing bacpac file using sql package? The maximum size of 32GB is auto-sizing, but my actual DB size is over 35GB. Can I get to use DatabaseMaximumSize=(INT60) instead of DatabaseMaximumSize=(INT32)?

eg. import parameter /p:DatabaseEdition=GeneralPurpose /p:DatabaseServiceObjective=GP_Gen5_2 /p:DatabaseMaximumSize=(INT60)

Answer (score 0):

As Microsoft Docs, "/p: DatabaseMaximumSize=(INT32)" Defines the maximum size in GB of an Azure SQL Database. So, I realized database size is know as in GB. So I used
for database size 60GB:
"import parameter /p:DatabaseEdition=GeneralPurpose /p:DatabaseServiceObjective=GP_Gen5_2/ p: DatabaseMaximumSize=60"